# Questions about mounting

Tags: terminal, mount, thunar

Thunar mounts usb drive automatically in '/run/media/*user*/*some random number*'.

1. How can i mount it in the same way in the terminal, instead of specifying mount location?
2. Why doesn't thunar require root access for mounting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thunar (and all other GUI file managers like Nautilus or Dolphin) uses [UDisks](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/udisks/) for mounting. UDisks is a system daemon that runs with as root and uses [polkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit) to allow unprivileged users (in certain situations) to perform privileged storage operations like mounting. The idea is to make device mounting (especially for removable devices like USB flash drives) more user friendly. It also allows automatic mounting of inserted devices without prompting the user for password.

You can use `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdxY` to mount a device the same way Thunar does, see [udisksctl man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/udisksctl.1.html) for details.

Comment: Why does it allow unprivileged users to perform mounting? Why not ask for password?

Comment: @nk2 because that's pretty much of a hassle, not providing any additional safety in modern desktop scenarios. What would be the actual upside of being asked a password? Who or what would benefit? (If you are inclined to say "security", you will need to define whose security of what against what, specifically.)

Comment: (note that Linux systems usually do no automatic execution of programs on attached media, and that such mounts are pretty universally `nosuid` etc.)